# How redirect route to other web project with RouteValueDictionary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 web projects in ASP.NET MVC4. I use following method in my first project. This works for me:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
         action = "Login",
         controller = "Account",
         area = "", 
    }));
    return;
}
```

But now I use that code in my second project and want to redirect route to "Login" action in first project.

How can I solve this?

I can make custom `<a href = "www.myFirstSiteName.com/Account/Login">` link, but can not use it in `RedirectToRouteResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectResult`

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("www.myFirstSiteName.com/Account/Login");
```

You may need to add *Protocol* like `http://` or `https://` as per your *Requirements*.